# SQLite.swift performing a left join and using the data

Tags: swift, sqlite, sqlite.swift

I am trying to perform a left join

```
SELECT TProgram.ProgramName, TProgram.ProgramPath From TProgram
LEFT JOIN TIcons ON TIcons.ProgramName = TProgram.ProgramName
WHERE TIcons.ProgramName IS NULL
GROUP BY TProgram.ProgramName
```

with swift. So i did the following.

```
let program = db["TProgram"]
let icons = db["TIcons"]
let programNameDB = Expression<String>("ProgramName")
let programNameDBI = Expression<String>("ProgramName")
let programPathDB = Expression<String>("ProgramPath")
let all = program.select(programNameDB, programPathDB).join(Query.JoinType.LeftOuter, icons, on: programNameDB == icons[programNameDBI]).filter(programNameDBI == "").group(programNameDB)
```

i cannot check if it is working because the following results in an `fatal error: ambiguous column name:`

```
let item = all.first!
let arr = Array(all)
```

If I try `println(all)` I can see "TProgram" in the debug console.

How can i access the data?

**UPDATE**
I tried the following. Error is gone but no values seem to be in there.

```
func readTProgramNames() -> (Query){
    let program = db["TProgram"]
    let icons = db["TIcons"]
    let programNameDB = Expression<String>("ProgramName")
    let programNameDBI = Expression<String>("ProgramName")
    let programPathDB = Expression<String>("ProgramPath")
    let all = program
        .select(program[programNameDB], program[programPathDB])
        .join(.LeftOuter, icons, on: program[programNameDB] == icons[programNameDBI])
        .filter(icons[programNameDBI] == "")
        .group(program[programNameDB])

    let item = all.first!

    println(item[program[programNameDB]])

    return all
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it. The `String?` wer important and the `.leftouter`

```
func readTProgramNames(){
    let program = db["TProgram"]
    let icons = db["TIcons"]
    let programNameDB = Expression<String?>("ProgramName")
    let programNameDBI = Expression<String?>("ProgramName")
    let programPathDB = Expression<String?>("ProgramPath")
    //let all = table.select(programNameDB, programPathDB).group(programNameDB)
    //let all = program.join("LEFT OUTER", icons, on: programNameDB == icons[programNameDBI])
    let all = program
        .select(program[programNameDB], program[programPathDB])
        .join(.LeftOuter, icons, on: program[programNameDB] == icons[programNameDBI])
        .filter(icons[programNameDBI] == nil)
        .group(program[programNameDB])

    for item in all{
        println("programName: \(item[program[programNameDB]]!)")
    }
}
```